# How can I add more columns to the list of files in a File Share in Azure Storage Explorer?

Tags: file-management, azure

I'm using [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) (the latest version, 1.15.1) on macOS and Windows to view and maintain different types of storage accounts. When exploring File Shares, the columns are limited to Name and Size, but I'd like to see other kind of data (e.g. Last Modified) too. Is this possible? Right-clicking the column doesn't work, and neither do I see anything in the settings.

[image]

Other storage types (e.g. blobs) show much more columns, and other properties *are* visible when viewing file properties:

[image]

The Action and Properties tabs of the file share weren't much help either:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Bottom-left, do you have a collapsed Actions or Properties panel? I am on the Windows 1.5.1 client, and I have more columns than you although I see now way to add/remove columns. The properties panel though might get you going.

Comment: @spikey_richie thanks for the suggestion but no luck there :( I'm curious what you see with 1.5.1, that seems to be a much older version.

Comment: Sorry, typo. I am also on v1.15.1. Maybe have a look at https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/issues and raise a new issue if you feel it necessary.